# How do I convert a string to a double in C++?

Tags: c++

I've attempted to use `atof()` (which I think is way off) and `stringstream`. I feel like `stringstream` is the answer, but I'm so unfamiliar with it. Based on some Google searches, YouTube videos, and some time at cplusplus.com, my syntax looks like below. I'm pulling data from a `.csv` file and attempting to put it into a `std::vector<double>`:

```
while (file.good() )
    {
    getline(file,line,',');
    stringstream convert (line);
    convert = myvector[i];
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: [Browsing my trusty C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), `std::stod` sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Simply googling the title of your question would give you many answers.

Comment: I googled "c++ convert string to double" and the first two matches were std::stod and atof. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/ Both look good.

Comment: `std::stod()` is best, but even in the code provided, you could just replace `convert = myvector[i];` with `convert >> myvector[i];` instead - assuming the `vector` has been preallocated beforehand, otherwise you would need to use `double value; convert >> value; myvector.push_back(value);` instead . Also, you should use `std::istringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading doubles from a stream (file) we can simplify this:

```
double  value;
while(file >> value) {
    myvector.push_back(value);
}
```

The `operator>>` will read from a stream into the type you want and do the conversion automatically (if the conversions exists).

You could use a `stringstream` as an intermediate if each line had more information on it. Like a word an integer and a double.

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    std::string word;
    int         integer;
    double      real;

    lineStream >> word >> integer >> real;
}
```

But this is overkill if you just have a single number on each line.

Now lets look at a `csv` file.
This is a line based file but each value is seporated by `,`. So here you would read a line then loop over that line and read the value followed by the comma.

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    double value;
    char   comma;
    while(lineStream >> value) {
        // You successfully read a value
        if (!(lineStream >> comma && comma == ',')) {
            break; //  No comma so this line is finished break out of the loop.
        }
    }
}
```

Don't put a test for `good()` in the while condition.
[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/14065)

Also worth a read:
[How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140/14065)